# Is it ok to ask others to say if a movie has copied another movie based on watching?

Tags: discussion

I have watched two movies and I found the stories very similar (with just a little differences in details).

I searched the internet but I couldn't find any source relating the two works.

That's because one of the works is not famous. It's an Iranian movie. So may be other users can't find a source as well.

So I think I can at least give a link to the complete movie of the Iranian film and ask others to compare the two films based on their watching.

Is it considered on-topic? Is it considered opinion-based?

Comment: It would absolutely be on-topic to ask if one movie inspired another *based on any reliable sources* (for example, interviews with the makers of the less well-known film). If you're just wanting people to comment on the apparent similarity, that would be decidedly iffy

Comment: One can find, like, anything being similar to anything else. Unless you have some serious reason to think two works are related, the question could be received badly.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to say this. But I think it looks selfish to expect others to give time and data to download and/or watch a complete movie only to say if that's similar to another movie or not. The OP just wants a confirmation in this case.

So maybe on-topic. But selfish.

Comment: It is kind of up to the person if they want to invest that time or not - not sure it is selfish to ask a question, they are not forcing someone

Comment: I do think the question will be down-voted and close-voted though - for being opinion based or just a bad question for the site.

Comment: I'm happy to invest time if I think *I'll* enjoy it.